# xamarin.forms can't build FIRST project in visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

**=========================================**

**UPDATE: This is answered in my post below.**

**=========================================**

Scenario:

1. Fresh Windows 10 installation with updates.
2. Installed Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin development features.
3. Updated Xamarin in Tools, Options, Xamarin, Check Updates...
4. Checked to make sure Android SDKs are installed.
5. Set Droid project to build & deploy in config manager as well as the Portable library (build only).
6. Build just hangs..................

Tried other suggestions:

1. Delete obj, bin, and Xamarin zip folders...restart, clean, rebuild.
2. Updating Xamarin.Forms to version v2.3.1.114 (tried 2.2 first). Then updating Xamarin.Android.* to versions v23.3.0 (tried version with 2.2. first)
3. Linking Xamarin.Android .dlls manually.
4. Downloading android_m2repository_r29.zip or other zips as suggested in other posts and extracting manually to Xamarin folders.
5. Deleted .vs folder and rebuilt
6. Deleted temp and Xamarin folders in app data folder.

**Xamarin Error Log**

**Xamarin.VisualStudio.Forms.Intellisense.ProjectTypeResolver Error: 0 : [2016-08-31 14:37:37.5635] An error occurred searching types for the given assembly
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.MetadataReader.IMetadataTables'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{D8F579AB-402D-4B8E-82D9-5D63B1065C68}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).**

So nothing works...Why can't I build this project?  It just hangs every time.

Comment: Check the log of Xamarin in VS2015, and paste the error. Help -> Xamarin -> open logs

Comment: Xamarin.VisualStudio.Forms.Intellisense.ProjectTypeResolver Error: 0 : [2016-08-31 14:37:37.5635] An error occurred searching types for the given assembly
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.MetadataReader.IMetadataTables'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{D8F579AB-402D-4B8E-82D9-5D63B1065C68}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: Looked this up and deleted .vs folder and it rebuilt, but now I get Resource.Attribute does not contain a definition for actionBarSize.  I've seen this error before also and cannot find a fix for it.  Same error appears in Xamarin error logs, too.

Comment: C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Xamarin  go to this route and paste the route with your user here.

Comment: yes. What is your user name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122340/discussion-between-marcos-jose-perez-perez-and-foreverlearningandcoding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: The build takes forever and a day, but it will finish.**

**Explanation of fix:**

You can go to this path: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Xamarin\

Then delete all the versioned folders WITHIN these subfolders (such as 23.0.0):

1. Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable
2. Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
3. Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
4. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
5. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView
6. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter
7. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView
8. Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable

Now rebuild BUT when you rebuild, Visual Studio 2015 will download LOTS of files to get the build to work.  **It may take 15-60 minutes for you to wait for it all to re-download and there is no message from Visual Studio that it is downloading files.** You just have to already know that you should wait for all the files to download. (I just kept an eye on every folder and watched new folders automatically being created in them by Visual Studio).

Once it is done, the build will work and you can Run the project.

Hopefully this helps others who ran into similar issues.  If it helped you post a comment and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Ok try install this Emulator, I don't use the generic this is better

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/

when you install donwload a device and verify the you donwload de SDK corresponding to the device you donwload.

Compile again using this Emulator

---

and let me know is that solve your problem.

Comment: this didn't work. i just keep getting brought back to the other errors

Comment: also, i have tried reinstalling xamarin before after deleting folders but it didn't work

Comment: Show me the errors that you have. In what moment appear the error. You trying compiling a project in what OS

Comment: Windows OS.  There is no error other than the Xamarin log error listed in the main post above.  It is just stuck in build mode the whole time.

Comment: What emulator are you using exist 3

Visual Android Emulator,

Xamarin Android Player ,

The Generic.

Comment: the one that comes with Visual Studio 2015 Community.  everything came together in one package: VS2015, Xamarin, Android SDK, emulators, etc.. It was all installed with VS2015 Community. let me check the version

Comment: it says 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone (Android 4.4 - API 19)

Comment: i figured it out...there was no error and will post up top what to do.  truly appreciate your willingness to help!

Comment: regards. Thanks to you.